# Transfer value to an external method in Java

Tags: java, swing, external

So I have a program that's meant to update a thermometer bar (using drawRect) dynamically based on the position of a JSlider. What I'm trying to do is to pass that value to an external method so I can use it to update the size of the rectangle. I'm a VB guy so I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it.

Here's my main class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class ThermoProject extends JApplet
{
    JSlider mySlider;
    JPanel sliderPanel;
    JPanel northernPanel = new NorthPanel();
    JLabel printLabel = new JLabel("");
    static int fillSize = 0;
    int topSize = 100;


    public void init() //init is the "main" for an applet
    {
        buildSliderPanel();
        sliderPanel.setBackground(Color.gray);
        add(northernPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH); //separate class
        add(printLabel, BorderLayout.WEST); //add label to top
        add(sliderPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH); //add the panel to the south of the borderLayout
    }



    private void buildSliderPanel()
    {
        sliderPanel = new JPanel();
        //JSlider(direction, beginning, end, initial location)
        mySlider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 100, 0);
        mySlider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
        mySlider.setPaintTicks(true);
        mySlider.setPaintLabels(true);
        mySlider.setSnapToTicks(true);

        //add listener
        mySlider.addChangeListener(new SliderListener());

        //add to panel
        sliderPanel.add(mySlider);

    }


    public class SliderListener implements ChangeListener
    {

        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
        {
            //change when slider is moved
            updateThermo(mySlider.getValue());
            //topSize = 100 - fillSize;
            //drawRect(x, y, width, height)
            //fillRect(x, y, width, height)
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my subclass, which is mostly used to build a separate JPanel.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class NorthPanel extends JPanel
{
    JPanel theNorthernPanel;
    int fillSize = 0;

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        //drawRect() and fillRect() args are x, y, width, height
        g.drawRect(90, 90, 200, 30);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(90, 90, fillSize, 30);
    }

    public NorthPanel()
    {
        JPanel theNorthernPanel = new JPanel();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        JLabel printLabel = new JLabel(String.valueOf(fillSize));
        theNorthernPanel.add(printLabel);
        add(theNorthernPanel);

    }

    public void updateThermo(int temperature)
    {
        fillSize = temperature;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

NorthPanel northernPanel = new NorthPanel(); // to declare

and then,

northernPanel.updateThermo(mySlider.getValue()); //to call

Comment: Thanks, it was just me instansiating northenPanel wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You paint code is broken, start by taking a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details.

To call a method, you need a reference to the instance of the class you want to call...

Start by changing

```
JPanel northernPanel = new NorthPanel();
```

to

```
NorthPanel northernPanel = new NorthPanel();
```

And then use it to call the method....

```
northernPanel.updateThermo(mySlider.getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive that you should change the content of the `SliderListener` to:

```
public class SliderListener implements ChangeListener
{

    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
    {
        //change when slider is moved
        ((NorthPanel)northernPanel).updateThermo(mySlider.getValue());  
        //topSize = 100 - fillSize;
        //drawRect(x, y, width, height)
        //fillRect(x, y, width, height)
        northernPanel.repaint();
    }
}
```

In the code snippet you presented you're trying to invoke a member of `ThermoProject`.
Also take notion of casting to `NorthPanel` which is necessary, because you declared `northernPanel` as a more general type:

```
JPanel northernPanel = new NorthPanel();
```